# Sign in with Apple SwiftUI Xcode 12.5.1 not working on one app but exact same code works perfect on another

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui

1. I am not using pods but rather Swift Package Manager for Firebase.
2. Here is my app file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
    
    @main
    struct two_screensApp: App {
        
        init() {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(UserAuth())
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Here is my content view:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import CryptoKit
import FirebaseAuth
import AuthenticationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if !userAuth.isLoggedin{
                LoginView()
            } else {
                DashboardView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Here is my Auth File:

```
import Combine

class UserAuth: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isLoggedin: Bool = false
    
    func login() {
        self.isLoggedin = true
    }
}
```

5. Lastly, here is my LoginView that has the SignInWithApple Button

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
import CryptoKit
import FirebaseAuth

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject  var  userAuth: UserAuth
    @State var currentNonce:String?
    
    //Hashing function using CryptoKit
    func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
        let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
        let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
        let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
            return String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()
        
        return hashString
    }
    
    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        let charset: Array<Character> =
            Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
        var result = ""
        var remainingLength = length
        
        while remainingLength > 0 {
            let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
                var random: UInt8 = 0
                let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
                if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                    fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
                }
                return random
            }
            
            randoms.forEach { random in
                if remainingLength == 0 {
                    return
                }
                
                if random < charset.count {
                    result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                    remainingLength -= 1
                }
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.orange
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                SignInWithAppleButton(
                    
                    //Request
                    onRequest: { request in
                        let nonce = randomNonceString()
                        currentNonce = nonce
                        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
                    },
                    
                    //Completion
                    onCompletion: { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let authResults):
                            switch authResults.credential {
                            case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                                
                                guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                                    fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                                }
                                guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                                    fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                                }
                                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                                    print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",idToken: idTokenString,rawNonce: nonce)
                                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                                    if (error != nil) {
                                        // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
                                        // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
                                        // your request to Apple.
                                        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                                        return
                                    }
                                    print("signed in")
                                    self.userAuth.login()
                                }
                                
                                print("\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid))")
                            default:
                                break
                                
                            }
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                        
                    }
                )
                .frame(width: 280, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.init(top: 400, leading: 50, bottom: 20, trailing: 50))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this app I get the following error:

```
2021-07-18 08:56:24.350661-0500 two screens[2350:796467] 8.3.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.
```

And this error:

```
ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

The app still starts and I see the login view with the Sign in with apple Button. When I press the button I get this error.

```
Optional("An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.")
```

Comment: The lifecycle is likely the difference. The other app likely uses the `AppDelegate` lifecycle and this app uses the SwiftUI lifecycle. If you add an `AppDelegate` it might resolve.

Comment: Add UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor to your SwiftUI App to configure Firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365575/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-how-to-connect-the-facebook-sdk/68369393#68369393

Answer (score 0):

I'd try what the error message says and check if your application delegate supports the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. You're calling some code that thinks it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

add an AppDelegate it might resolve or like mentioned just do what the error code says in output I’m trying this on my end to see if I get the same —-